# probabilty of n within a time interval t

Tags: probability

Imagine that there is a web page with a button, that if clicked, would provide a reward.
There are N users and the web page is available for a time T eg. 2 hours.

How would you go about calculating the probability that N users click the button in a particular interval t eg. 10ms?
Assume that all N users visit the site during the 2 hours.
Each user can click the button only once.

Comment: It seems that there are two pieces of information needed: [1] Assuming that each user clicks the button at some point in the interval of duration $T$, are these button clicks randomly distributed throughout the interval $T$? [2] Suppose that you identify a specific sub-interval $t$, and with each user $x$ let $E_x$ denote the event that $x$ clicks the button during this sub-interval.  Are these events independent of each other?  That is, if event $E_x$ occurs, does this affect the probability that event $E_y$ occurs?

Comment: Also, do you assume each of the $N$ users actually visits the site and clicks the button at some point during the availability period? If not, what's your model for whether a user clicks it (and how many times, and when)?

Comment: @user2661923 assume two cases, one with a uniform distribution and the second case would be first-come-first-serve (not sure which distribution this is but it would look like a downward sloping graph, like a rush for a sale at a store)
The events are independent of each other.

Comment: @Karl, each user can click only once. And yes, assume each of the N users visits and clicks during the interval.